# I need to load 100 fonts into my web page for viewing

Tags: javascript, fonts, loading, html, local

What is the BEST WAY to load 100+ fonts to a web page for viewing.  I have a small sign company and I need the online user to be able to see THEIR CUSTOM TEXT in the font of THEIR CHOICE.  Most will NOT have these fonts installed.  Many thanks.  I do know about the @font-face and local but I was looking for a quicker and shorter way. Maybe using a variable passed from a select box value?

Answer (score 1):

Don't load them all at once. Use XmlHttpRequests to load the fonts on demand.

If you ABSOLUTELY MUST load all fonts, then base64 encode them in a CSS file `fonts.css` then serve CSS files gzipped...

But seriously, you should not do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Generate pictures on server. Then client PC may survive your page. Or may not.

Why won't you use pagination and show only 10 at once?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution, I haven't tested with fonts. The idea is there are two pages, say a splash page and the real page. On the splash page, you download all your static images, fonts, etc by creating fake IMG tags on the page. Then the files are in cache. As you loop through your files, to down load, pause between them so as to minimize the chance of blocking the UI.  This is a strategy I was planning to use for javascript files, but should work with other static content.

```
//Load but doesn't execute. Gets the file into the local cache.
var preload;
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false)
{
    preload = function (file)
    {
        new Image().src = file;
    };
}
else
{
    preload = function (file)
    {
        //it really is an object
        var obj = document.createElement('object'),
            body = document.body;
        obj.width = 0;
        obj.height = 0;
        obj.data = file;
        body.appendChild(obj);
    };
}

function preloadAll(urls)
{
    processArray(urls, preload
    //omit optional callback
    );
}

function processArray(items, process, callback)
{
    var todo = items.concat(); //create a clone of the original
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        process(todo.shift());
        if (todo.length > 0)
        {
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
        } else
        {
            if (typeof callback === 'function')
            {
                callback(items);
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}
```